# how to get SKU based stock from big commerce API in .net

Tags: bigcommerce

how to get SKU based stock from big commerce API in .net
I my application there is 21 sku under single product based on the size .I placed notify me option in my site.So use this api and get the product stock level send to the particular customer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below api:

/api/v2/products/{product_id}/skus?sku={value}

It will return details about product options for a given product id(Base product).
You can use product Id(Product Option) that you get from above api to get further details about product using:

/api/v2/products/{product_id}